# Как получить уникальные значения из бд?

Tags: mysql

Как получить список уникальных `year` из бд mysql.

```
Есть 30 записей (`id`, `name`, `year`). 

1, test, 2015
2, test, 2016
3, test, 2014
4, test, 2015
5, test, 2015
```

Хочется получить список из

```
2015, 2014, 2016
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**distinct** - для выбора уникальных элементов

```
  select distinct year
    from table
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, все работает.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров рад помочь, значит отмечайте сообщение как правильный ответ)

Comment: 4 минуты требуется:) для того чтобы отметить как правильный, не я это придумал.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров не знал, извините)